# nltk: parsing raw text into *binary* syntax trees without having to write my own grammar

Tags: nltk

I'm trying to use the nltk package to parse strings of sentences such that it can separate sentences into a structure like this:

[image]

Note the binary structure of the tree. This is pretty standard in the field of syntax (in linguistics) and I know there exist built in tools for it but for some reason everything I find regarding nltk involves writing your own CFG. I would like to find a way to extrapolate this *without* having to write a CFG for this. Perhaps a way to import grammars from nltk or something. This should absolutely exist in this day and age.